# pCloud indicator doesn't show up in Vanilla GNOME but exists in Ubuntu's customized session [18.10]

Tags: gnome, indicator

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10. I like pure GNOME, so I've installed vanilla GNOME session using this guide: https://itsfoss.com/vanilla-gnome-ubuntu/ .
I am using pCloud app (which is provided by AppImage file) and I saw that it has an indicator (what suprosed me) which show only in Ubuntu session, but not in vanilla one.
Some  time ago I was using Fedora with GNOME and there wasn't any indicator too.
How does it work? Why pCloud notification shows only in Ubuntu's GNOME, but not in vanilla version? I feel that I don't understand appindicator mechanism.
To compare - Telegram (installed by Flathub) indicator shows up in "every" GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

The pCloud app indicator is a "legacy tray icon" which is not the same as an app indicator supported by GNOME. Thankfully, there is a GNOME extension "Top Icons Plus" which allows you to put these icons back in the top panel.

From the project's Github readme:

> Many applications, such as chat clients, downloaders, and some media players, are meant to run long-term in the background even after you close their window. These applications remain accessible by adding an icon to the GNOME Shell Legacy Tray. However, the Legacy Tray is hidden until you push your mouse into the lower-left of the screen and click on the small tab that appears. TopIcons Plus brings all icons back to the top panel, so that it's easier to keep track of apps running in the backround.

So, here's how you can get your pCloud tray icon back in vanilla GNOME on Ubuntu 18.04* (for now)

1. Stop the pcloud application if it's running.
2. Open the following link for Gnome extension -> https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/
3. Turn on and install the extension -> https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZltdV7ZxR4rjGkKFmzCfMBR5deEiVRFhcu7
4. Start the pCloud Drive application and you should see the tray icon -> https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ76dV7ZBLFP2JmV6FuVDShH1zHnV0vHLUc7

***CAVEAT:** Top Icons Plus extension is no longer actively maintained. There's a discussion of the reasons here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/topicons-plus-wont-work-on-gnome-3-26-replace-with-an-alternative-extension/31762/9 
As of now 10/26/2018, it still works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1, GNOME 3.28.2 (vanilla GNOME on Xorg session).